# Facebook login on Android/phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to login to facebook via phonegap on android phone, but it's not working.
Instead, it shows this warning `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///android_asset/www/facebook.html from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/login.php?action=like&api_key=APIKEY&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D0%23cb%3Df3ee611618%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252Ff3596433dc%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&locale=en_US&max_rows=1&sdk=joey&show_faces=true&width=200. Domains, protocols and ports must match`

How to develop this?

Thanks

Comment: How u implement FB using Graph API or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the only working method to use Facebook Connect in Phonegap+Android is with this Phonegap plugin:
https://github.com/jos3000/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Facebook

In Phonegap+iOS you can use the *ChildBrowser* method.